# Creating a DB in Azure using the Management SDK

Tags: azure, azure-management-api

I've got this code for programmatically creating a database in Azure, [from here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-add-certificate-to-15a6b1a2):

```
public static string subscriptionId = "ec19938f-6348-4182-83cf-091370e65";
public static string base64EncodedCertificate = "???"; // what goes here?
static SubscriptionCloudCredentials getCredentials()
{
    return new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedCertificate)));
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SqlManagementClient client = new SqlManagementClient(getCredentials());
    client.Databases.Create("mysub1", new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql.Models.DatabaseCreateParameters()
    {
        Name = "newdbtest",
        MaximumDatabaseSizeInGB = 1,
        CollationName = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
        Edition = "Web"
    });

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I believe the next step is to get a certificate, and upload it to Azure. From [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-certs-create/),

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName yourdomain.cloudapp.net -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "your-password" -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -FilePath ".\my-cert-file.pfx" -Password $password
```

Now I have the certificate, how do I get the value for `base64EncodedCertificate`?

Second part of the question: what do I do with the .cer file? i.e. I presume I upload this into Azure. Do I have to create a 'cloud service'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pfx file is not the right one. You need a file with `.publishsettings` extension. 
You can get that file from Azure PowerShell via this command:

```
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile
```

More details about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385850(v=nav.70).aspx)

This is xml file in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublishData>
  <PublishProfile SchemaVersion="2.0" PublishMethod="AzureServiceManagementAPI">
    <Subscription
      ServiceManagementUrl="https://management.core.windows.net"
      Id="{GUID With subscription ID}"
      Name="{Subscription name}"
      ManagementCertificate="{Long Base64 encoded value}" />
  </PublishProfile>
</PublishData>
```

The value you are looking for is `ManagementCertificate`.

When I did the same thing you are doing, I've included .publishsettings file into deployment and then read it in this code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;


public CertificateCloudCredentials GetCredentials()
{
    try
    {
        var certFileStream = this.GetCertificateString();
        var xDocument = XDocument.Load(certFileStream);

        var publishProfileElement = xDocument.Descendants("PublishProfile").Single();
        var subscriptionElement = publishProfileElement.Descendants("Subscription").Single();

        var certificateAttribute = publishProfileElement.Attribute("ManagementCertificate") ?? subscriptionElement.Attribute("ManagementCertificate");
        var subscriptionId = subscriptionElement.Attribute("Id").Value;

        var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certificateAttribute.Value));

        var cloudCredentials = new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, cert);

        return cloudCredentials;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw new DomainException("Could not parse publish settings file: {0}", exception.Message);
    }
}


private Stream GetCertificateString()
{
    var filePath = @"C:\Full\Path\To\file.publishsettings";

    var allBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

    var stream = new MemoryStream(allBytes);

    return stream;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting: `The term 'Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile' is not recognized as the name of...`

Comment: @Sean latest version of Azure PowerShell?

Comment: Ok, that's working. But now I get `The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.`

Comment: Never ye mind, kind sir! Seems I just copied my subscription ID incorrectly. Thank you!

Comment: Why is there not just a link in the Azure Portal to download that file / copy that value? Or does it still require you to do the certificate thing? i.e. what is `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile` actually doing?

Comment: @Sean good staff it is working. I've not used it for couple of years now and everything is changed! There used to be a link that just gave you that file - you are correct here. But I can't find it anywhere now. `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile` creates a certificate for you - same as you would do manually in your question. If you go to old portal you'll see a new cert issued today - that corresponds to that publish settings file.